# Problem socket TCP IP in C# received only one message from client before stop

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, server, client

I've a problem with my server in tcp/ip, because after received one message doesn't work.
I don't know if use a while true, and how to put it.
Any suggestion?

Thank you

```
   my method()

        sdk = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        sdk.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 8052));
        sdk.Listen(10);
        Socket accepted = sdk.Accept();
        Buffer = new byte[accepted.SendBufferSize];
        int bytesRead = accepted.Receive(Buffer);
        byte[] formatted = new byte[bytesRead];
        for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead; i++)
        {
            formatted[i] = Buffer[i];
        }
        Debug.Log("\t Server" + "\n");
        string stradata = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(formatted);
        Debug.Log("-->" + "" + stradata + "\n\n");
        testo = stradata;
        //sdk.Close();   tried to uncomment 
        //accepted.Close(); tried to uncomment
```

Comment: A connection has three properties 1) Source IP address 2) Destination IP address 3) Port number.  You can only have one connection where all three properties are the same.  You are trying to open a second connection with the same parameters.

Comment: @jdweng a TCP connection has 4 unique properties, the three you listed plus the Source Port, the source port is generally assigned automatically by the OS for outbound connections, however you can set it manually.

Comment: Source Port since it is assigned automatically doesn't isn't a factor in blocking a 2nd connection.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read from the socket continually, until you have read all the data that you want

```
    sdk = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    sdk.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 8052));
    sdk.Listen(10);
    Socket accepted = sdk.Accept();
    Buffer = new byte[accepted.SendBufferSize];
    while (true)
    {
        // begin reading continually from the socket

        // Socket::Receive() will block until it gets some data
        // Exception handling required here for when client closes connection
        int bytesRead = accepted.Receive(Buffer);
        byte[] formatted = new byte[bytesRead];
        for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead; i++)
        {
            formatted[i] = Buffer[i];
        }
        Debug.Log("\t Server" + "\n");
        string stradata = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(formatted);
        Debug.Log("-->" + "" + stradata + "\n\n");

        // Need to add some exit logic here eg,
        if(stradata.Contains("EXIT"))
            break;
    }
    sdk.Close(); 
    accepted.Close();
```